# Centered UITextField text moving unexpectedly on edit

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield

I have a centered `UITextField` inside a `UICollectionView` Cell, but the text moves weirdly to the right when editing. What is causing the problem?

```swift
let textLabel: UITextField = {
        let label = UITextField()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.minimumFontSize = 12
        return label
    }()
```

```swift
addSubview(textLabel)
textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
textLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
```

Here is a screen capture of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Could you please show more code? Not just some out of context snippets.

Comment: Have you turn `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of textLabel to false ?

Comment: yes I did. @andesta.erfan

Comment: @matt Sorry I just want to make it cleaner, which part of the code should I provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Turns out the `UITextfield`'s height is too large, I reduced its height and everything works perfectly now. Thanks for your kind help!

```swift
textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
textLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
textLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
```